# Exporting data from the function [mysql, node.js, discord.js]

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, discord.js

I have such a problem here with exporting data from functions. I do not know if it can be done at all, but I do not see any other solution here. My problem is that I am exporting a function and I would like to export the result of this function, so in this case I have MYSQL. I cannot add `rows` to `module.exports = {sql, rows}` because I get a message that `rows` is undefined. I am asking for help or for some other solution.

```
//------------------------------
 index.js
//------------------------------

const mysql = require('mysql')
const db = require('./database')

var con = mysql.createConnection({
        host: db.host,
        user: db.user,
        password: db.password,
        database: db.database
})

con.connect(err => {
        if(err) console.log(err)
})

function sql(sql){
        con.query(sql, (err, rows) => {
            if(err) console.log(err)

        })
}

module.exports = { sql, rows }

// con.end()

//------------------------------
 Command file
//------------------------------

const sql = require('./../config/test')

sql.sql("SELECT * FROM `servers`")
console.log(sql.rows)

//------------------------------
 Console error
//------------------------------
(node:30132) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: rows is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of a [Callback function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function) in which you can use the data how you want. By passing a function as a parameter to the `sql` function, you can invoke that callback function with the `rows` fetched from the database as a parameter.

Take a look at the code I edited for you:

Your index.js

```js
/* Skipped all code above that isn't important for this example */

function sql(query, callback){
    con.query(query, (err, rows) => {
        if(err) console.log(err);

        callback(rows);
    });
}

module.exports = {sql}
```

Your Command file

```js
const queryHandler = require('./../config/test');

// Call the sql function and pass a callback as the 2nd parameter
queryHandler.sql("SELECT * FROM `servers`", (rows) => {
    // Do whatever you want with the rows
    console.log(rows);
});
```

Give it a try and see how it goes